# Can't unbind mouse button from keymap

Tags: key-bindings, dired, keymap, mouse

This is more of an academic question than a practical one, as I've already worked around it. However, the curiosity / mystery is killing me. I'm about 10 days into emacs, so new to a lot of this.

As I've been experimenting and learning about keymaps, I've been trying to unbind [mouse-2] from dired without success. From the dired.el source, I see this:

```lisp
    (defvar dired-mode-map
      ;; This looks ugly when substitute-command-keys uses C-d instead d:
      ;;  (define-key dired-mode-map "\C-d" 'dired-flag-file-deletion)
      (let ((map (make-keymap)))
        (set-keymap-parent map special-mode-map)
        (define-key map [mouse-2] 'dired-mouse-find-file-other-window)
        (define-key map [follow-link] 'mouse-face)
```

However, when I try to unbind it with:

```lisp
    (define-key dired-mode-map [mouse-2] nil)
```

It remains bound. I've tried every method I can think of to unbind this, without success. I'm curious if someone can point me to what might be going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that.  Did you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)?

If I do that, and then I do what you tried:

```lisp
(define-key dired-mode-map [mouse-2] nil)
```

Then `mouse-2` is no longer bound in `dired-mode-map`.

To see that, you can load library [`help-fns+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) and use `C-h M-k dired-mode-map` before and after evaluating that sexp.

Or you can just try `mouse-2` in a Dired buffer, or use `C-h k` and click `mouse-2` -- its global binding is in effect.

Comment: Thank you Drew. I am still figuring things out (30 year tech veteran, but completely new to both emacs and lisp). I tried with a clean install and got the same results as you did. I now realize that I'm using evil mode (which I want), but didn't fully understand how all these things are interacting with each-other. It appears that key-binding can get complicated as different folks build different layers on top of basic functionality.